# View a replicated Access 2000 database in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've an old replicated Access 2000 database. I want to get to the code and some of the forms as I'd like to revive parts of it, and also see how I dealt with things back then.

I have the Access 2000 CD, but it was an upgrade from Access 97 and the Access 97 CD is too damaged now to load. Access 2016, which I have now, won't open replicated databases.

Is there any way I can open or convert the .mdb file? I only need to view it in design mode.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need Access 2010 or lower to open it.

If the database doesn't contain confidential data, you could upload it to a file hoster and some good soul might convert it for you.

If it does, you will have to go scouting for a used copy of an old version, I'm afraid.